# Firebase setup on WebStorm

Tags: android, firebase, gradle, react-native, webstorm

I'm currently developing an app on React Native and, after trying Meteor as a backend, wanted to try Firebase.
I followed the Firebase setup instruction and had a first issue when I had to sync my Gradle file: I just can't via WebStorm.

Now, I don't know if this has an impact but my simple RN project which looks like this

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase';

const firebaseConfig = {
        apiKey: "***",
        authDomain: "**.firebaseapp.com",
        databaseURL: "https://**.firebaseio.com",
    };
const firebaseApp = firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

***

componentDidMount(){
        const rootRef = firebaseApp.database().ref().child('react');
        const speedRef = rootRef.child('speed');
        speedRef.on('value', snap => {
            this.setState({
                speed: snap.val(),
            });
        });
    }
```

...doesn't get any data from Firebase (whereas, of course there is some) and I don't see any error message! 
**My app launches properly and display basic data.**

Could you let me know if this already happened to you?
Is it possible to use only WebStorm for RN + Firebase?

PS: I setup Google services etc...as requested in the docs of course.

Answer (score 1):

Well...so:

- the public database access was not enabled on Firebase, thus, because not authenticated in my test App, it was normal to see nothing --> now it is ok
- I realized I don't need to setup an Android mobile app to make RN and [Firebase work](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html)

So no problem anymore, if there are lost people like me out there I hope it helped!